# Count factor levels inside another factor - R

Tags: r

Assume that we have a data frame with hundreds of observations of cars. Each observation can be grouped by model, brand and country.

How can we count how many models of cars are produced in each country?

I tried:

```
janitor::tabyl(data,  coutry, model)
```

But I get the amount of each observation by model per country. However, I am looking for the amount and list of models that are from a particular country, for each country.

example:

```
Country  n    model
Italy    4    Punto, Panda, Mito, Giulietta
Germany  3    Polo, Golf, X5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in dplyr

```r
df <- data.frame(Country = c("Italy","Italy",
                             "Italy","Italy","Germany","Germany","Germany"),
                   Model = c("Punto","Panda",
                             "Mito","Mito","Polo","Golf","Golf")
      )

library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Country) %>%
  summarise(n = n_distinct(Model),
            model = toString(unique(Model)), .groups = 'drop')

# A tibble: 2 x 3
  Country     n model             
  <chr>   <int> <chr>             
1 Germany     2 Polo, Golf        
2 Italy       3 Punto, Panda, Mito
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you @AnilGoyal, but it's almost correct. It lists all the models, but I would like just the levels. In addition, it is still counting the number of observations and not to the levels of Models. You can notice it if you try to add more duplicate model types.

Comment: see revised answer